# Python what does self[name] = value means?

Tags: python, django, sequence

Python newbie here. I am reading part of code from Taiga project which is based on Django. I am having trouble to understand one line of the code.

```
class Response(SimpleTemplateResponse):
    def __init__(self, data=None, status=None,
                 template_name=None, headers=None,
                 exception=False, content_type=None):
        super().__init__(None, status=status)
        self.data = data
        self.template_name = template_name
        self.exception = exception
        self.content_type = content_type

        if headers:
            for name, value in six.iteritems(headers):
                self[name] = value
```

I don't quite understand the last line. self[name] = value. What does that exactly means? Is that creating a dict? If yes, how do I call this dict or make reference to this dict outside of the class? If not, what does it do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taiga is based on django, which is where [`SimpleTemplateResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/template/response/#SimpleTemplateResponse) comes from. It is a subclass of [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) which is a dict-like object.

Now, the loop is checking first if there is a name `headers` that is not None, or False. If it is set, then it is assuming that `headers` is a dictionary, and looping through each key/value pair of the dictionary with iteritems. It then duplicates the same keys and values as properties of the class, with `self[name] = value`.

In effect, what this means is that if there is are headers, they are accessible directly in the class as keys.

Here is a simple example of what its doing:

```
>>> class MyFoo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self._data = {}
...     def __setitem__(self, a, b):
...         self._data[a] = b
...     def __getitem__(self, a):
...         return self._data[a]
...     def __delitem__(self, a):
...         del self._data[a]
...     def populate(self, d):
...        if d:
...           for k,v in d.iteritems():
...               self[k] = v
...
>>> headers = {'User-Agent': 'Python/2.7.5'}
>>> a = MyFoo()
>>> a.populate(headers)
>>> a['User-Agent']
'Python/2.7.5'
```

You can see that `MyFoo` is a simple class, but it defines some special methods `__setitem__`, `__getitem__`, `__delitem__`. These methods let any object of the class act like a dictionary.

The `populate` method is doing what is being done in the loop in the original source; and once its run - all keys of the dictionary become keys of the resulting `MyFoo` object.

In the [source of the HttpResponse class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py) you'll note the same `__setitem__`, `__getitem__`, `__delitem__` are defined (scroll down to [line 140](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L140)).

Comment: So this is no difference than define a dict inside the class as an normal attribute and assign the key/value pair to it?

Comment: It is something like that, except it adds a few magic methods so that the object itself works like a dictionary.

Comment: Awesome example! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Response` class is implementing sequence protocol. That's It'll be having `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` magic methods defined in it, which will make it to behave like any sequence or dictionary.

Comment: I just read some articles about sequence protocol and your answer really helped me a lot in understanding what happened under the hood. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In `Django` [HttpResponse](https://github.com/gsb-eng/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L31) has been implemented as a container (`HTTP response class with dictionary-accessed headers`)

More about containers..

In `Python` one can create a [container](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) objects by implementing certain magic methods..

A sample container for better understanding..

```
>>> class Container(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.d = {}
...     def __setitem__(self, i, k):
...         print 'Setitem called for assignment!'
...         self.d[i] = k
...     def __getitem__(self, i):
...         print 'Getitem called for assignment!'
...         return self.d[i]
...     def __delitem__(self, i):
...         print 'Delitem called for assignment!'
...         del self.d[i]
...
```

Since we've implemented `__setitem__` for `assiginment` and `__getitem__` for `get` and `__delitem__` for `deleting an item`, now `Container` object supports all these three operations..

`Assigning` value to some attribute for Container object..

```
>>> obj = Container()
>>> obj[1] = 'Assigned 1'
Setitem called for assignment!
```

When ever we try to assign something to this container by calling like `obj[--some_attr--] = value`, python checks for `__setitem__` method for this class and it's developers duty to write their own logic where to store that values, whether it's a dict or some other data structure..

`Retrieving` a value from the container...

```
>>> obj[1]
Getitem called for retrieving!
'Assigned 1'
```

When ever we try to retrieve something to from container by calling like `obj[--some_attr--]`, python checks for `__getitem__` method for this object and it's developers duty to write their own logic to return or do some operation inside..

`Delete` value from the container..

```
>>> del obj[1]
Delitem called for deleting item!
```

When ever we try to delete something to from container by calling like `del obj[--some_attr--]`, python checks for `__delitem__` method for this object...

So where ever you see `self[item] = value` or `self[item]` or `del self[item]` is same as doing this with object.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SimpleTemplateResponse` object (the parent class of `Response`) will have a `__getitem__` and a `__setitem__` method.

I don't know what the `__getitem__` or `__setitem__` methods that are inherited from `SimpleTemplateResponse` will do, but I'm guessing that, in this case, it will return an attribute of a response object.

Essentially what you're doing is setting a particular attribute of the `Response` object to the value based on the rules in the inherited `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods.

[You can read more here.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types)

Answer (score -1):

A python class is behaving like a dictionary.
When you do:
    self["foo"] = 1234
You can access it like a normal attribute of self:
    print(self.foo)
The same holds for functions. It is used to dynamically extend a class.